# how to find out exactly where the error occurred (in what place) Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Node.getLocalName()" because "need" is null

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming. I have an Android application - a video player (contains a lot of activity, so showing everything here is not an option). The question is: What does this error mean?

I don't remember writing such a method (I did it using a video tutorial). But if I did write it, how do I find it among the heap of activity?

I find it by searching, but this method is not used in the code I created, but in some system ones. The neural network says that I need to find a failure by setting a point in front of the place where this method is called. But the bottom line is that I have no idea where this call is happening! Help please.

I tried to drive in the search (Ctrl+R), but nothing was found there. Another search found some code built into android studio, but it isn't in my code (the error is in my code, right? I'm not even sure about that). I also tried to reboot everything that is possible. I didn't find the answer on the Internet.

Comment: The exception comes with a stacktrace, that stacktrace shows all the method calls leading up to the exception. You use the stacktrace to find where in your code the error originates. Possibly you're passing a wrong (or a `null`) value and this then triggers an exception deeper in some library. Or possibly you're running into a bug in a library you use.